# POST image file to a server using SwiftyJSON or Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to take a picture on an iPad and POST that image file to a server using SwiftyJSON or Alamofire.  Do I have to convert the file to base64EncodedString or is there a way to upload the file directly?

Comment: How is the web service designed? Does it directly accept file uploads? Do the uploads need to contain MultipartFormData boundaries? Does it only accept base64EncodedStrings in JSON in a POST? Do you have cURL example that works with the service?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) sendImageToServer
{
   UIImage *yourImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage);
   NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [imageData length]];

   // Init the URLRequest
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:@"http://yoururl.domain"]]];
   [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [request setHTTPBody:imageData];

   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   if (connection) {
          // response data of the request
   }
}
```